# ERRO :Meu código trava sem nenhum erro

Tags: python, login

Estou começando a aprender python e queria criar uma especie de login, só que o código termina sem ter escolhido para termina.

```
from time import sleep
```

print('=='*20)
print('=='*8,'LOGIN','=='*8)
print('=='*19)
print()
print('DIGITE 1 PARA SAIR DO SISTEMA\nDIGITE 2 PARA CONTINUAR ')
opc=int(input(' 1 ou 2 : '))

while True :
    login = []
    senha = []

`if opc == 1:
    print()
    print('FINALIZANDO')
    print()
    sleep(3)
    break

if opc == 2 :
    print('PROCESSANDO')
    print()
    sleep(4)
    print('DIGITE 1 PARA CADASTRO\nDIGITE 2 PARA LOGIN')
    opc2 = int(input('1 OU 2 : '))

    if opc2 == 1:
        print()
        print('=='*5,'PROCESSO DE CADASTRAMENTO','=='*5)
        print()
        login_1 = input('LOGIN : ')
        login=login+[login_1]
        sleep(2)
        print('SALVO')
        senha_2 = input('SENHA : ')
        senha=senha+[senha_2]
        sleep(2)
        print('SALVO')
        print()
        opc3=input('DESEJA FAZER O LOGIN DIGITE 1 OU 2 PARA SAIR : ') #ERRO APÓS ESCOLHER
        if opc3 == 2:
            print()
            print('FINALIZANDO')
            sleep(2)
            break
        if opc3 == 1:
            print()
            print('==' * 5, 'LOGIN', '==' * 5)
            print()
            login_1 = input('LOGIN :')
            if login_1 in login:
                print()
                senha_1 = input('SENHA :')
                if senha_1 in senha:
                    print()
                    print('PROCESSANDO')
                    sleep(3)
                    print('LOGIN EFETUADO')
                    break
                else:
                    print('SENHA INCORRETA')
                    print()
                    print('DIGITE NOVAMENTE A SENHA')
                    print()
                    if senha_1 in senha:
                        print()
                        print('PROCESSANDO')
                        sleep(3)
                        print('LOGIN EFETUADO')
                        break
                    else:
                        break
            else:
                print('VOCÊ NÃO TEM CADASTRO')
                break
        else:
            break
    else:
        break

    if opc2 == 2:
        print()
        print('=='*5,'LOGIN','=='*5)
        print()
        login_1 = input('LOGIN :')
        if login_1 in login:
            print()
            senha_1 = input('SENHA :')
            if senha_1 in senha:
                print()
                print('PROCESSANDO')
                sleep(3)
                print('LOGIN EFETUADO')
                break
            else:
                print('SENHA INCORRETA')
                print()
                print('DIGITE NOVAMENTE A SENHA')
                print()
                if senha_1 in senha:
                    print()
                    print('PROCESSANDO')
                    sleep(3)
                    print('LOGIN EFETUADO')
                    break
        else:
            print('VOCÊ NÃO TEM CADASTRO')
            break
    else:
        break

else:
    break`

Comment: O código é confuso demais. Se simplificá-lo o problema provavelmente some sozinho.

Comment: Programar, entre muitas outras coisas, vai envolver você identificar padrões e separar o problema em pequenas partes usando raciocínio lógico. No começo pode ser confuso, mas vá insistindo até esse seu código ficar curtinho, somente com o mínimo de passos necessários para chegar ao resultado. Remova repetições e use os recursos da linguagem para controlar o fluxo. Deixe a máquina tomar as decisôes em vez de você mesmo fazer todas as combinações possíveis e escrever uma a uma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se voce postou o seu código aqui exatamente do jeito que voce fez ai, então o erro esta no recuo do primeiro while true que voce fez.
Ele vai ficar infinitamente rodando as duas linhas seguintes que definem as variaveis login e senha.
Corrija os recuos/identação do seu programa e seja feliz.

Answer (score 0):

Como disse Bacco, é interessante separarmos os problemas em porções pequenas e irmos resolvendo essas pequenas porções uma a uma.

O seu código possui alguns problemas  relacionados a sintase e lógica. Então vamos por partes. Abaixo vou deixar um código que captura uma entrada e a imprime.

Repare que a parte que captura uma entrada está em uma função, assim você consegue separar as responsabilidades de cada trecho do código, além de deixar as coisas mais claras:

```
# funcao para coleta de dados
def coleta_entrada():
    entrada = input("digite alguma coisa: \n")
    return entrada


while True:  # loop infinitio para executar sua rotina
    retorno = coleta_entrada()
    print('voce digitou: {} \n'.format(retorno))
```

Acho que esse é um começo para o que você quer fazer...